# How to send data between 2 independent components in react js without using context api or redux

Tags: reactjs, components

I am experienced react developer but I don't know the answer of this question. In an interview they ask me this question.

pass data between two independent component without using context api or redux ?

can anybody give me the answer?

Comment: Please give more context, "two independent component" - they share same parent? "Without redux or context" - redux uses context. Do you have a code example?

Comment: In an interview they ask me this question no dependency on each other

Comment: What was your answer? As saying "passing props" is too obvious.

Comment: I said we can pass through the url params or through local storage but he said this is not right approach that's why i thought to ask about that may be there is some other thing which i don't know

Comment: You pass data as props from a common parent, no need to overthink this.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually one of the first things to learn in React. You store the data in a component that is a parent of the two independent components and pass the data as props to them.

There is a root component in all react apps usually App.js so all react components have a common parent at some point in the tree.

Checkout [Lifting up state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) in the docs.

Comment: your answer makes sense but this is not the answer he was expecting i also gave him that answer btw i found this article https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-communicate-between-independent-components-in-reactjs

Comment: I think you should question your interviewer as well, and ask him why you need to a contrived answer to a quite simple problem. The article you linked literally says that this is not conventional.

Answer (score 1):

Thats a tricky question.

- [Props drilling](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/prop-drilling/) is a valid answer but too obvious.
- Redux uses Context API to pass its Store and hooks, so you basically asking **how to pass data without Context API and through props**.

Let's say we have a value that we wish to pass from component A to B.

The main problem in this question is **how to notify component B** that he needs to read the value.

Answers like "use local storage", "read url params" and just "fetch values from remote server" are partly correct as they don't address the mentioned problem.

Therefore the solution is similar [to what MobX does](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react-lite).

The value passed must be application-global (as [subscribe pattern](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) or observables), and notify the component to render itself (`forceRender`) on value change, then read the global value.

Comment: Why is a correct answer, not right because it is too obvious? This seems to me to be an unnecessarily complicated answer to a quite simple problem. Is this the recommended way in the docs or any large codebase? React already does this for you, that's why you are using the framework in the first place.

Comment: Read the link on props drilling.

Comment: I've read that article before, what would you like to point out?

Comment: "Why is a correct answer, not right because it is too obvious", although you can definitely always do props drilling, it's an anti-pattern. I think its a fair question and would fix it to "how to pass data without Context API and through props"

Comment: This "anti-pattern" is a common pattern seen in a lot of codebases and the react core team recommends it as a first case solution, before picking up any state management libraries. `It can be an anti-pattern !== it is an anti-pattern`. The question is straight forward, no need to make assumption, or over-think it IMO.

Comment: @knada you are right my friend but i already told you that that was an interview and what we can do if a person want to hear that solution just to check person knowledge or problem solving ability.